# Conditional formatting: color a cell based on a comparison with another cell

Tags: google-sheets, boolean, conditional-statements, conditional-formatting, boolean-logic

Consider the following table in **Google Sheets**:

```
       |   A     |   B   |  C
   ----+---------+-------+--------
    1  | product | price | target
    2  | apple   | 5     | 6
    3  | pear    | 7     | 4 
    4  | banana  | 2     | 2
```

What I am looking to do is applying some conditional formatting, but I cannot figure this one out so I hope somene can help me.

What I want to achieve:

- For every product, check the `price` against the `target`
- If the current price is ** equal to** or **under** the target, I would like to target price to color Green. This would be the case for cells `C2` and `C4`
- If the current price is **above** the target price, I would like the target price to color Red. This is the case for `C3`.

Is there any way to achieve this? Whenever a target turns green, it means that for me, this product is in the buying zone and I should look into it more closely.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

green:

```
=((C2=B2)+(B2<C2))*(C2<>"")
```

red:

```
=B2>C2
```

[image]